# How to automatically format on save

Tags: neovim

I'm trying to setup auto-format on save with neovim.  I do not want to use an lsp plugin to do this.

The example below is my attempt at calling the [black](https://github.com/psf/black) formatter for python files.

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("AutoFormat", {})

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd(
    "BufWritePre",
    {
        pattern = "*.py",
        group = "AutoFormat",
        callback = function()
            vim.cmd("!black --quiet %")            
            -- vim.cmd("write!")
        end,
    }
)
```

The callback function runs as expected, but the code isn't formatted.  Here is what I see in the nvim output area.

```
:!black --quiet test.py
"test.py" 5L, 86B written
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I've also tried adding the extra `vim.cmd("write!")` which is commented in the example above because it seemed to have no affect.

When I manually the command with `!black --quiet %` the buffer is formatted, so I think I have the correct command.

What I'd like to have happen is I write to the file with `:w`, the code is formatted and saved.  Is this possible?

*Note: I plan on adding other languages (Go, Rust, SQL), so I plan to add more autocmds to the script.*

Answer (score 5):

Spent some more time on this and figured out how to get the functionality I want.

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("AutoFormat", {})

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd(
    "BufWritePost",
    {
        pattern = "*.py",
        group = "AutoFormat",
        callback = function()
            vim.cmd("silent !black --quiet %")            
            vim.cmd("edit")
        end,
    }
)
```

Switching to `BufWritePost` to make sure the file had been saved first, then allowing black to format the file and reloading with the `:edit` command seems to work.